# Load data at startup in Metro style app

Tags: javascript, html, microsoft-metro

I am trying to develop an app that uses the camera and stores the photo in the app's local folder written in javascript and html5. I have 3 pages that uses the same files(the images) and it is too expensive to load the images at each page's ready section so i was thinking about loading the images to an array or list with the getFilesAsync() method when the app starts up and then making it public with the WinJS.Namespace.define. The solution works for a few amount of data but when a lot of pictures stored in the images folder the async operation takes more time so when I try to access the files on another page it is still undefined.

Do you have any idea how to load data at the launch of the app and make it accessable from other pages and force the program to wait until it finishes? I know this is the exact opposite of async programming but I do not see any other solution. Thank you!

Comment: Are you using actual page navigation -- e.g you change the window.location.href, or are you using WinJS navigation?

Comment: I am using WinJS page navigation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a promise, and promise chain to allow you to wait on the completion:

```
var getFiles = Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.getStorageFilderSync("Your folder").then(function(folder) {
    return folder.getFilesAsync();
});

/* somewhere else in your app */
getFile.done(doWorkWithResult);
```

You can call the done from your other pages; if getFilesAsync has completed, then it will return immediately and won't re-run the query. If it's not ready, then it will just wait until it is complete.

There is a nice sample [here](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Folder-enumeration-sample-33ebd000) that has some more worked examples.

Comment: I was thinking about that, but I need to get the "images" folder first, which is another async operation. Can you please write me a code that includes these two op in one function? I've red a lot of doc about this but I am still not sure I know the right methods for chaining async calls.

Comment: You could write it yourself ;)

Let me update the sample. :) [Edited]

Comment: Thank you very much. I am new to StackOverflow so what sould I do to express my gratitude beside words? I mean where should I vote for this useful info?:)

Comment: Just vote up, and accept as answer if it solves your problem.